# Qt4 QtRuby installer

Tags: qt4, installation, qtruby

I'm following this tutorial for QtRuby 
--@ http://tom.paschenda.org/blog/?p=38

At one point I have to go on this site :
--@ vision.eng.shu.ac.uk/mmvlwiki/index.php/Qt4-QtRuby_installer_for_Microsoft_Windows

but it seems down...So is there any alternative sites ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please improve your accept rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3a_6DC6JyLZV8J%3avision.eng.shu.ac.uk/mmvlwiki/index.php/Qt4-QtRuby_installer_for_Microsoft_Windows%20vision.eng.shu.ac.uk/mmvlwiki/index.php/Qt4-QtRuby_installer_for_Microsoft_Windows&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=safari) from 16 Oct 2011 20:17:28 GMT.

Or try this more recent [tutorial](http://dr1ku.posterous.com/qt-461-ruby-187-on-win32).

Comment: well the cached page works but you can't download the installer :s

Comment: Both links are dead meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

All the links above are very much outdated or broken.

See https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/ for a maintained version of qtruby.